# How do I add JLabels over the Graphics class

Tags: java

I created a test class for my pong game to be able to add JLabels on my JFrame. However when I used the graphics class, the JLabel does not show up and I can't fix the problem.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    JLabel label;

    public Main() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(null);

        label = new JLabel("Text inside");
        label.setBounds(1100, 500, 200, 50);
        p.add(label);
        add(p);

        setSize(1700, 712);
        setTitle("Title");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1700, 712);
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.drawRect(1050, 450, 300, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: What has the title to do with your question?

Comment: There are few answers. Can you review them and comment whether they are of help? Also as @QBrute noted, you can be a bit more clear on what you wanted to ask in the first place.

Comment: @QBrute I just forgot to change the title from a previous question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaDoc for [`Window.paint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)) clearly states:

> If this method is reimplemented, super.paint(g) should be called so that lightweight components are properly rendered.

You don't do this, so your lightweight components (i.e. your `JLabel`s) are no longer rendered.